# 使用しないリソースファイルの整理方法（あるいはゴミが散らからないリソースファイルの管理方法）は？

Tags: android

Android アプリケーションを開発していると、あれこれとアイコンを試すうちに、使わない png ファイルやら xml ファイルやらが幾つものフォルダに散在しがちになります。

そうなってしまった`res`フォルダ（特に`drawable-*`）を整理する良い方法は無いでしょうか？
或いは、そうならないように`res`フォルダを管理する方法は無いでしょうか？
（ベストで無くても、僕はこうやってるよ、という方法を教えて頂ければ嬉しいです）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studioの`Analyze`->`Inspect Code...`を使用するのはどうでしょうか？
確か使っていないリソースなどを見つけてくれます

Comment: ありがとうございます。
IntelliJ IDEA でも `Anayyze -> Inspect Code ...` が使えました。

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse+ADTでしたら、
プロジェクトを右クリックして
`Android Tools`→`Run Lint: Check for Common Errors`を実行すると、
`Looks for unused resources`といった感じで使ってないリソースを警告してくれます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
IntelliJ IDEA では、`Inspection Results for ...`ビューの`Android Lint` > `Unused resources` で警告してくれました。